# Redirect to another component by clicking a button which is a part of existing component

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, jsx

I am new to react. I am trying to Redirect to a component by clicking a button which is a part of the existing rendered component.
Now I want that when I click the button, new component should be rendered and the existing one should be hidden(the button also).

```
render(){
    return(

            <div className='container'>
            <table className='table table-striped'>
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>User_Id</th>
                        <th>User_Name</th>
                        <th>Email</th>
                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    {this.state.arr.map((card)=>{
                        return(
                            <tr>
                                <td>{card.user_id}</td>
                                <td>{card.user_name}</td>
                                <td>{card.email}</td>
                                <td>
                                    <button className="btn btn-outline-primary ml-2 my-2 my-sm-0">Edit</button>
   //click here(the Edit button) to Redirect to another component
                                </td>
                                <td><button className="btn btn-outline-primary ml-2 my-2 my-sm-0">Delete</button></td>
                            </tr>       
                    ) })}
                </tbody>
             </table>
        </div>
    )

}
```

and the component to be rendered is-

```
export default class Edit extends Component{
    render(){
      return(
        <div>
          <h1>Edit User.</h1>
        </div>
       )
    }
 }
```

Comment: Pls show your App.js with Route `react-router-dom`

Answer (score 0):

```
import { Route } from 'react-router-dom'

const Button = () => (
  <Route render={({ history}) => (
    <button
      type='button'
      onClick={() => { history.push('/new-location') }}
    >
      Click Me!
    </button>
  )} />
)
```

Comment: Guide me where should I place this code. And what else is needed

Answer (score 0):

`react-router-dom` has a `Link` component which handles this on its own. All you have to do is to provide the URL where it should redirect to under the `to` prop. Just replace your `button` elements with the `Link` component:

```
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';

<Link to="/url-to-edit" className="btn btn-outline-primary ml-2 my-2 my-sm-0">Edit</Link>
```

[More about the `Link` component](https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/api/Link).

Comment: @MrigankShekharShringi Do you have some sort of `Router` component in your application? Would you mind updating you original post with that code?